Is there a bijection $b: \mathbb{R} \to \{0,1\} \times \mathbb{R}$
Title says it all, we are interested in if there is a bijection $b: \mathbb{R} \to \{0,1\} \times \mathbb{R}$. Informally, are the real numbers bijective to "twice" the real numbers. Note that we are NOT talking about the real interval from 0 to 1 when we write $\{0,1\}$.We stumbled across this talking about the Banach–Tarski paradox. We do not understand the paradox, but it seemed somewhat like it was saying that such a bijection exists. Clearly if this were the case, the wikipedia article would be much simpler though.

Yes your statement is true. This is generalised and proven by cardinals/ cardinal arithmetic. This link (or any book/ basic course in set theory) should help you: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number

This is much, much simpler than Banach-Tarski.

In fact, there’s a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for any positive integer $n$

Yes. It's a theorem of set theory that for every infinite set $X$, there is a bijection between $X$ and $\{0,1\}\times X$. Or in the language of cardinal arithmetic, $2\kappa=\kappa$ for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$.
We don't need to appeal to this general theorem in your case, though. Here's a totally explicit bijection $\mathbb{R}\to \{0,1\}\times\mathbb{R}$:
$$r\mapsto \begin{cases} (0,\log(r))& r>0\\
(1,\log(-(r-1)))& r\leq 0\text{ and }r\in\mathbb{Z}\\
(1,\log(-r)) & r\leq 0\text{ and }r\notin\mathbb{Z}\end{cases}$$
This has nothing to do with Banach-Tarski, though. Banach-Tarski doesn't just give a bijection between a ball and two balls of the same volume: this is easy. The amazing feat of Banach-Tarski is that the finitely many pieces in the decomposition of the ball are reassembled into two balls using only rigid motions of $\mathbb{R}^3$!
